# Как передавать параметры между окнами PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Добрый день.
Необходимо передавать параметры между окнами в PyQt5. Язык соответственно python.
Допустим при нажатии на кнопку, у меня вызывается доп окно. С этим я разобрался

```
def add_book(self):
    # в скобках self -> передаем ссылку на родителя, чтобы окно можно было сделать модальным
    self.window_add = AddBookWindow(self)
    # делаем окно модальным
    self.window_add.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
    #self.window_add.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
    self.window_add.show()
```

Пусть при нажатии на кнопку на дополнительном окне в главное окно передается цифра 10.

```
class AddBookWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Add_book.Ui_Add_book):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # закрыть окно
        self.b_back.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.send_to_main.clicked.connect(self.some_method)

    def some_method(self):
        # Передача цифры 10 в главное окно
```

Как мне передать цифру 10 в главное окно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На данном примере создается 2 окна:
Одно основное(`Main`) и диалоговое (`Dialog`), которое вызывается при нажатии на кнопку `"нажми"` и становится модальным, в самом диалоге при вводе значений в `self.edit` и нажатии на кнопку(`'Нажми чтобы отобразить'`) вызывается функция, которая передает текст из `self.edit.text()` в `self.label_main.setText()`, который находится в основном окне благодаря наследовании диалогового окна основным окном `self.dialog = Dialog(self)`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(root, **kwargs)
        self.main = root
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('введите что нибудь')
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Нажми чтобы отобразить')
        button.clicked.connect(self.push)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def push(self):
        self.main.label_main.setText(self.edit.text())
        self.close()


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dialog = Dialog(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.label_main = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Нажми')
        button.clicked.connect(self.dialog.exec)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_main)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: а если дополнительное окно QMainWindow, будут какие-то принципиальные изменения?

Comment: @Дитрий Астапенко не будет, только будет проблема на примере этого кода будет в том что `layout` нужно будет связываться с `qframe`

Comment: в общем случае, чтобы менее тесная связь была, чтобы диалог меньше об основном окне знал (для повторного использования), можно свой сигнал в диалоге создать (чтобы сразу текст посылать) или просто выставленный атрибут диалога  проверять по окончанию `exec()`.

Comment: @jfs согласен можно сделать так же как вы сделали в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803237/255866) )