# Как передавать переменные между окнами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

В своей программе внедрил голосовой помощник, который озвучивает действия пользователя. То есть, если он нажмет на кнопку *0* или *1*, воспроизводится mp3 файл, который озвучивает эту цифру. На скриншоте предоставлены изображения *основного окна* (на заднем плане) и модального *окна настроек* голосового помощника, в котором можно выбрать язык озвучивания.

[image: Скриншот программы]

**Сейчас это работает так**: при нажатии на кнопку *Сохранить* открывается файл *settings.txt*, находит там строчку *language* и переписывает его на *english*, *russian* или *none*, в зависимости от отмеченной пользователем радиокнопки.
А когда пользователь в основном окне нажимает на *0* или *1*, этот файл открывается, там ищется строчка *language=язык*, и через *if* воспроизводится нужный аудиофайл.

В коде это все выглядит не очень элегантно и у меня складывается мнение, что я написал какой-то костыль. Отсюда возникает вопрос: **как правильно передавать переменные между окнами?**

Comment: Через обработку события закрытия модального окна (сигналы/слоты).

Comment: Т.к. выбор языка должен сохраняться не только на время этой сессии, но и для будущих сеансов, то сохранять в настройки в файлик, в принципе, правильно.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как передавать параметры между окнами PyQt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801706/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-pyqt5/801714#801714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно свой сигнал определить, чтобы значения между окнами передавать. К примеру, вот диалог, который позволяет выбрать между несколькими языками:

[image: settings dialog]

```
class SettingsDialog(QDialog):
    selected = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle('Settings')

        # init UI
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)
        radiobuttons = []
        for i, rb in enumerate(map(QRadioButton, "en ru none".split())):
            radiobuttons.append(rb)
            grid.addWidget(rb, 1, i)  # first row, i-th column
        bb = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        grid.addWidget(bb, 2, 1, 1, 3)  # second row, span 3 columns

        def emit_language():
            lang = next((rb.text() for rb in radiobuttons if rb.isChecked()),
                        None)
            if lang:  # emit if something is selected
                self.selected.emit(lang)
        bb.accepted.connect(emit_language)
        bb.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        bb.accepted.connect(self.accept)
```

По нажатию ОК, посылается сигнал, если выбран язык.

Связать значение с другим окном, можно с помощью обычного слота:

```
dialog.selected.connect(label.setText)  # update label on language selection
```

Полный пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Emit new signal, connect slot."""
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QDialogButtonBox,
                             QGridLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QRadioButton,
                             QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

main_widget = QWidget()
main_widget.setWindowTitle('Communicate between windows')
label = QLabel('nothing selected yet')
button = QPushButton('Select Language')

layout = QVBoxLayout()
main_widget.setLayout(layout)
layout.addWidget(label)
layout.addWidget(button)

dialog = SettingsDialog()
dialog.selected.connect(label.setText)  # update label on language selection
button.clicked.connect(dialog.exec_)  # open dialog

main_widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В каком формате (json, sqlite) и сохранять ли вообще на диск явно/неявно и как часто с диска читать настройки можно в отдельный от GUI класс с настройками вынести, чтобы в одном месте это определялось (`Settings`). К примеру, вместо `label.setText` писать `settings.set_language`:

```
dialog.selected.connect(settings.set_language)
```

Другие части могут подписаться на события, генерируемые `settings` объектом. Таким образом `label.setText` будет вызван каким бы способом `settings.language` не поменялся.